# How to get `count` in the last line printed correctly?

Tags: node.js

I am testing [NEDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) and encounter a problem I don't understand: 
In this testnedb.js:

```
var  Engine = require('nedb')
  , db = new Engine({ filename: 'my.db', autoload: true });

let count = 0
function insertRec(rec){
  db.insert(rec, function(err, doc){
   ++count;
   console.log("Inserted: ", count)
  });
}

let rec = {id: "s1", seq: "ACGTCGCG"}
insertRec(rec)
rec = {id: "s2", seq: "ACGTCGCG"}
insertRec(rec)
db.count({}, function (err, count) {
  console.log("Found: "+ count + "seqs")

})

db.find({id: /s/}, function (err, docs) {
  docs.map((doc) => {
    console.log("Found: " + doc.id)
  })
})

console.log("Inserted asasd: "+ count)
```

the last line seems to be executed first:

```
Inserted asasd: 0 // I would expect this to be printed last with count=2 not 0. 
Inserted:  1
Inserted:  2
Found: 2 seqs
Found: s2
Found: s1
```

It may have something to do with async/sync behavior, but I don't see where and how to control the flow.

Comment: See https://github.com/bajankristof/nedb-promises.

Comment: Hey can do you do a quick log of what "db.insert" returns?

Comment: If it returns promise..you can push for every db.insert ,push the value into an array.use Promise.all(array).then for a callback when all inserts are done?

Comment: It doesn't return anything, and one more hint from Webstorm debugger: it sees the last line as a anonymous function(?)